# How can I show that the function is twice differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have to show that the following function is twice differentiable,
and calculate the first and second derivatives:
$f\colon \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ ,
$$f(x)= \begin{bmatrix}
         x_1^{3}-x^{2}\\  e^{x_{1}+x_2^{2}}
        \end{bmatrix}.$$
My solution is: I have started with

$$Df(x)v=\begin{bmatrix}
         3x_1^{2}v_1 - v_2 \\ 
         e^{x_1+x_2^{2}}v_1 + 2x_2 e^{x_1 +x_2^{2}}v_2 \\
         \end{bmatrix}$$
and then I calculated $D^{2}f(x)(v,w)$.

**My question is: how can I show that $f$ is twice differentiable?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why ? i know that [Df(x)] must be 2*2 matrix and not Df(x)v

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I haven't seen that you applied $Df(x)$ to $v$. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: With the chain rule: if $f$ and $g$ are both $p$ times differentiable, then $g \circ f$ is also $p$ times differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $f$ is twice differentiable, just notice that both of its coordinates are indefinitely differentiable as:

- The first one is a polynomial.
- The second one is the composition of the exponential, which is indefinitely differentiable and a polynomial. And we know that the composition of two maps that are $n$ times differentiable is $n$ times differentiable.

To compute the derivatives, you have to use the chain rule for each coordinate.

Comment: so it is not enough to say directly that f is twice differentiable since $D^{2}f(x)v$ exists?

Comment: I just didn't understand how can i show it with those two points in your answer

Comment: @lipa How can you say that $D^2 f$ exists without understanding why it is differentiable?

Comment: To show that $Df, D^2 f$ exist, you don't have to say more than what I say in my answer. **Maybe it is to compute those that you have difficulties.** But that's a different story.